# What is the difference between a gapi access token and one created from the nodejs googleapis oauth2client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client, google-picker

I'm currently trying to figure out what the difference between [gapi](https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) oauth access tokens and access tokens created via the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) package is. There apparently is a difference, since when I try to use the access token generated by gapis to authenticate to [google picker](https://developers.google.com/picker) using `setOAuthToken()` only the gapi access token works. This is unfortunate, since I need to refresh tokens on the backed and I therefore cannot use gapi. When I try to use the googleapis token, I get prompted to sign in, which is also not very ideal.

The scopes for both are exactly the same and the client_id is the same. The only idea I have is, that it might have to do with the googleapis one being an `offline` token, but that shouldn't matter right?

The code for the picker is pretty much straight from their docs:

```
picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                            .setDeveloperKey(apiKey)
                            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
                            .setOAuthToken(access_token)
                            .build();
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

I have also seen a couple other people ask similar questions, but either their answers didn't fix anything (probably because some of the problems date back to 2012 and earlier).

**EDIT**: Nevermind. Somehow it resolved itself. I really have no idea why....

Comment: Hi @IcyTV, both of the access tokens - if valid, should allow you to authenticate. Are you using the `gapi` for server-side web apps? Can you provide more information on your situation?

Comment: @IcyTV did you solve this?

Comment: @aalimovs yes. But I really dont know what I changed to make it work. I think there was a problem with the way I was generating the tokens, but I don't really know... The Picker API is horribly outdated and has a LOT of wierd quirks that make no sense. For example: In my mobile app I had to open an In-App Browser, and open the web page in order to get the picker to work, since there isn't really an alternative and it wouldn't run straight in the app. There also is no way to properly display it on mobile.

Comment: @aalimovs also just tested it and apperantly it does not work...